# Could not load file or assembly while running in IIS 7.0 on a 64 bit OS

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to host a web application in a Windows 2008R2 server on IIS7.0 which is 64 bit. I had been running my application on IIS 5.1 XP machine which is 32 bit.

I have my DLLs built with the 'x86' option and also I have enabled "Enable 32 bit applications" to True and also set the managed pipeline to Classic in the application pool of my webservice.

Now I get the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services2,
>   Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[some value]' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Can someone tell me why this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

Just install Microsoft Web Services 2.0 : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1ba1f631-c3e7-420a-bc1e-ef18bab66122&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Can you set your DLLs to build with the AnyCPU option and report what happens?